# optimizing solution for calculating value at given index for a 2d array

Tags: python, optimization, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming

This is basically an interview style question that I need to solve, but I have only been able to find a O(m*n) solution. Is there any way this can be optimized further?

Write a function that takes a pair of indices for a 2D array and prints out the number at the provided indices where each number is the sum of the value to the left and above itself. the first row and the first column are filled with 1s. So the value at (row, col) is (row-1, col) + (row,col-1) :(0,0) is 1, (1,1) is 2, (2,1) is 3, (5,3) is 56 and so on.

Currently, I have a O(m**n) solution, but I need to optimize this further. this is my O(m*n) solution using dynamic programming:

```
from functools import lru_cache

def solution(m: int, n: int):
  @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
  def dp(row, col):
    if row == 0 or col == 0:
      return 1
    return dp(row - 1, col) + dp(row, col - 1)

  return dp(m, n)

row = int(input('row?\n'))
col = int(input('col?\n'))

print(solution(row, col))
```

Comment: you could precompute whole 2d array of "numbers" with  simple O(m*n) algorithm, then solution would be O(1). Also, I think there must be some pattern in those "numbers" and some equation to calculate this.

Answer (score 0):

**Some hint on optimization**

dp[i][j] = dp[j][i] as there is symmetry in the structure. You can use this to optimize the approach. But it will not change complexity of the algorithm.

**Alternate Solution:**

If you study the values carefully, you can find out that

dp[i][j] = <sup>(i+j)</sup>C<sub>i</sub> = <sup>(i+j)</sup>C<sub>j</sub>

Hope this can help you reach optimization you were looking for. It can be done in ~O(N log N) where N = i+j